# calling one step that triggers group of steps using cucumber

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium-android

I have Scenario-1, Scenario-2, and Scenario-3 that has 5 steps common.

Example:

```
Scenario-1:
Given User Step1
And User Step2
And User Step3
And User Step4
And User Step5
When User Completes 5 steps in X
Then User Signoff X

Scenario-2:
Given User Step1
And User Step2
And User Step3
And User Step4
And User Step5
When User Completes 5 steps in Y
Then User Signoff Y

Scenario-3:
Given User Step1
And User Step2
And User Step3
And User Step4
And User Step5
When User Completes 5 steps in Z
Then User Signoff Z
```

Instead of writing all the common 5 steps everytime can I call like **Step1to5**

```
Scenario-N
Given User Step1to5
When User Completes 5 steps in N
Then User Signoff N
```

Note: I came to know that in Specflow caling Steps from Step is removed in latest version, If calling Steps from Step is one option and I referred to JAVA framework there used one group tag to club the repeated steps into one common step, is there anything like that we can use in cucumber c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group common steps into a scenario background:

```
Feature: ...

Background:
    Given User Step1
    And User Step2
    And User Step3
    And User Step4
    And User Step5

Scenario: 1
    When User Completes 5 steps in X
    Then User Signoff X

Scenario: 2
    When User Completes 5 steps in Y
    Then User Signoff Y

Scenario: 3
    When User Completes 5 steps in Z
    Then User Signoff Z
```

The `Background` steps will be executed for each scenario in the feature. If some scenarios should not include those steps then move them into their own feature file.

If all you do is save 5 steps per scenario, I would argue that you don't need to eliminate this repetition. The goal of behavior-driven development tests is to communicate the behavior, *not eliminate code duplication*.

My recommendation is to keep the repeated steps in each scenario if moving them into a `Background` makes scenarios more difficult to understand. On the other hand, if moving the steps into a common `Background` makes the scenarios *easier* to understand, then definitely move the common steps out of the scenarios.

Comment: Great, One more doubt @greg What if we want to reuse User Signoff for each scenario at the end just like Background works. Is there any other tag that we can run at the end?

Comment: @AmanKhan: there is no way to include common steps *after* a scenario. Don't feel like you need to include "signing off" in the scenario, unless it is relevant to the use case.  Consider using an `[AfterScenario]` hook (see [SpecFlow hooks](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html) for more info). Signing out might be a necessary "cleanup operation" after each scenario that isn't important from a BDD perspective.

Comment: Great, thanks for the valuable information @GregBurghardt